# Find and replace " with nothing in a SQL server text field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to do this

```
replace(comments, '"', '')
```

but that didn't work

Any ideas on how to replace in a text field?

UPDATE

The error is

> argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Did you get an error message (if so, what was it)? What was the *WHOLE* command? What is the data type of the `comments` column? What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Why? I _hope_ that you aren't doing that for security reasons, because it would be useless and wrong.

Comment: It may seem a trite answer, but change the field from `text` to `NVARCHAR(max)`

Comment: This works fine for me: `SELECT REPLACE('Some text with "quotes"', '"', '')`. Give more detail about what's going on with your query and the surrounding code.

Comment: Are you sure you saved/used the result from replace? It doesn't change the string itself, it just returns a new string. That is, the line `replace(comments, ...);` does nothing as you do not manipulate or use the result.

Comment: the error is argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function

Comment: @Tamer, can you post the data of the table you are using REPLACE on?  That might help with an answer.

Comment: the data has "ADE For Restuarants" and I want to get rid of the double quotes

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - you can't do that with `TEXT`. The best answer is what @JNK proposed - change to a data type that isn't deprecated (`VARCHAR(MAX)`). Or even better, use `VARCHAR(something smaller)` if these are just short descriptions. `TEXT` in SQL Server is not the same thing as `TEXT` in Access, in the event that that's how you came to choose this data type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't to a lot of string functions in the `text` datatype.

**Don't use `text`.**

It's been deprecated for like 6 years now.  Use `varchar(max)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basics on replace;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Try Coalescing the string if the replace is being used elsewhere, otherwise it will return NULL.